# Почему новые размеры View не выводятся через Log? Вместо них выводятся старые значения, но при этом UI на устройстве запуска показывается правильно

Tags: android, view, height, width

```
   textView2.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewWidth = textView2.getWidth();
            viewHeight = textView2.getHeight();
            Log.i("userTest2020", String.valueOf("5) view width = "+viewWidth+"\n"+"view height = "+viewHeight));
            textView2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            800,400));
            viewWidth = textView2.getWidth();
            viewHeight = textView2.getHeight();
            Log.i("userTest2020", String.valueOf("4.4) view width = "+viewWidth+"\n"+"view height = "+viewHeight));
        };
    });
```

Console Result

```
2020-03-31 07:28:09.327 7049-7049/? I/userTest2020: 5) view width = 400
    view height = 200
2020-03-31 07:28:09.327 7049-7049/? I/userTest2020: 4.4) view width = 400
    view height = 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Размеры всех `View` пересчитываются системой в цикле, Ваш код вызывается в том же потоке, как бы между перерисовками. Получается, что команда

```
textView2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800,400));
```

Не изменяет размеры `View`, а только требует их изменения при перерисовке. Перерисовка происходит с огромной частотой, однако несколько последовательных строк кода почти всегда будут вызываться без перерисовки между ними. Выходит, что

```
viewWidth = textView2.getWidth();
viewHeight = textView2.getHeight();
```

Вызывается до перерисовки, когда `View` еще не пересчитал размеры.

Если Вам необходимо все-таки получить новые реальные размеры `View`, то единственный известный мне способ - использовать [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener?hl=ru)